# How to write a dynamic JPA query with a join?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I wish to implement a dynamic query in JPA, something like:

```
public Collection getOrderReportByUserName(String userName, Integer scripID, String orderStatus, String orderType) 
{     
    String strQuery = "Select o,t from OrderStock o,TradeStock t where o.userName.userName = "+ userName +" and t.userName.userName = "+ userName;
    if(scripID > 0)
    {
        strQuery += " and o.scripID.scripID = " + scripID;
    }
    if(orderStatus != null)
    {                        
        if(orderStatus.equals("Executed"))
        {
            strQuery += " and o.OrderID = t.OrderID and o.OrderStatus = " + orderStatus;
        }
        else
        {
            if(scripID > 0 && orderType != null)
            {
                String sQuery = "Select o from OrderStock o where o.UserName = " + userName +" and o.ScripID = "+ scripID+" and o.BuySell = "+ orderType;
                Collection<OrderStock> os = em.createQuery(sQuery).getResultList();
                Iterator it = os.iterator();
                Boolean ok = false;
                while(it.hasNext())
                {
                    OrderStock osObj  = (OrderStock)it.next();
                    Integer pending = osObj.getPendingQuantity();
                    Integer order = osObj.getOrderQuantity(); 
                    if(pending > 0 && ((order-pending) != 0))
                    {
                        ok = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(ok == true)
                {
                    strQuery += " and o.OrderID = t.OrderID and o.OrderStatus = " + orderStatus;
                }
                else
                {
                    strQuery += " and o.OrderStatus = " + orderStatus;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(orderType != null)
    {
        strQuery += " and o.BuySell = " + orderType;
    }
    Collection c = em.createQuery(strQuery).getResultList();
    return c;
}
```

I wish to bind the result to a datatable, but as you can see I want to return a collection consisting of 2 tables - `orderStock` and `tradeStock`. So how do I access this collection in my datatable? And how do I set the parameters of the resulting dynamic query?

Answer (score 1):

- For parameterizing your query see [this article](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/parameter).
- A collection returned by *getOrderReportByUserName* method will contain *Object[2]* elements. The first element will be an instance of *OrderStock* object and the second will be an instance of *TradeStock* object. To persist recieved entities you should use *persist* or *merge* methods of *EntityManager* class.
- If you are using JPA 2.0 you can use [Criteria API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjrij.html) to construct type-safe queries. It can be much better than hardcoding JPQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't created any variable with name `tradeStock` in ur code, but i assume that variable `'c'` in 3rd last line is your `'tradeStock'`.
So if you want to return 2 lists from your class, you should create a new class say `Stock`.
Stock will have 2 member lists i.e. `tradeStock` and `overStock` and getter/setter for them.
In this method create an instance of `Stock`.when  you fetch resultList from query set it in `Stock` and return `Stock` from method.